# Extracting data from scanned data

Tags: php, regex, neural-network

I get a text string from a scanned receipt. Here are couple of examples:

> George's Restaurant 300 72th Street Miami Beach fl 33141 305-864-5586 Server: Ronald 01/19/2013 Table 20/1 10:53 PM Guests: 1 10062 Reprint #: 1 Ferrari Carano Insalate Cesare Caprese with prosciutto FISH SPEC Spinach Ricotta Ravioli Seafood Pasta Ossobucco 47.00 7.50 9.50 25.95 15.95 19.95 29.95 Sub Total Tax 155.80 14.02 Total 169.82 169.82 Balance Due GRATUITY NOT INCLUDED!!! Thank you for your business

How do I identify what the total amount is in each case (169.82 and 52.88)?

I was thinking I can remove all non-numeric characters, split remaining into array and look for the largest. But it can get confusing with address and phone numbers. I suppose I need to make sure the word TOTAL, SUB-TOTAL, or AMOUNT DUE is close by.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Another example:

> 933 ece tur New OrlerS LA 70116 504.:25.1602 wwwfranksresta.ratnewor leans.com 219 KATHY U che 1750 Feb03'1 (7:-2PM Tbl 6/1 Gst 4 1 GARLICBREAD 2 Diet 2 Iced Tea 2 TASTE OF NO 1 Whole Muff 1 Alfredo 3,95 6.00 6.00 33.90 14.95 14.95 Food Tax TOTAL DUE 79.75 7.78 87.53

[image here](https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/07/50/c4/7e/receipt.jpg)

---

UPDATE:

It appears I need to look into neural networks to solve this.

Comment: In order for regex to help here, you need regular text.  I see the total amount located in very different contexts between the two texts.  Are these the _only_ two contexts in which the total would ever appear?

Comment: No, it depends on the receipt. Think restaurant receipt. They all could be pretty different but they all have total amount. I've never done anything like this. A bit lost.

Comment: in the 2nd one is the "S" a typo or a scanO ? in both cases its the largest 2dp number

Comment: You need to know what to search for, in order to write a regex pattern.

Comment: Both are scans. May or may not have $ in front.

Comment: but you dont have a $ in front on the 2nd one you have an S

Comment: the last example has no total, this is not realistically possible with any degree of accuracy

Comment: My apologies. Last example was cut off. I've replaced it and a link to the image before scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

function checktotal($rcpt) {
    if (preg_match_all('/(\d+\.\d{2})(?:\D|$)/', $rcpt, $match))
        echo 'Total is $' . max($match[1]) . "\n";
    else echo "No numbers!\n";
}

$rcpts = [
    "George's Restaurant 300 72th Street Miami Beach fl 33141 305-864-5586 Server: Ronald 01/19/2013 Table 20/1 10:53 PM Guests: 1 10062 Reprint #: 1 Ferrari Carano Insalate Cesare Caprese with prosciutto FISH SPEC Spinach Ricotta Ravioli Seafood Pasta Ossobucco 47.00 7.50 9.50 25.95 15.95 19.95 29.95 Sub Total Tax 155.80 14.02 Total 169.82 169.82 Balance Due GRATUITY NOT INCLUDED!!! Thank you for your business",
    "SUSHI HARA 8701 W PARMER LANE STE 2128 AUSTIN, TX 78729 123835218 ORDER: A9 Dine-in 25-Jan-2018 6 10 53 1 다tASHU DON SHRIMP TEMPURA (3PCS HARU COMBO SALMON ROLL $11.95 $8.95 $20.00 $7.95 to go Subtotal $48.85 $4.03 S52.88 Tax Total Order 05852ZSBGOW4M Thank you for dining at Sushi Hara",
    "933 ece tur New OrlerS LA 70116 504.:25.1602 wwwfranksresta.ratnewor leans.com 219 KATHY U che 1750 Feb03'1 (7:-2PM Tbl 6/1 Gst 4 1 GARLICBREAD 2 Diet 2 Iced Tea 2 TASTE OF NO 1 Whole Muff 1 Alfredo 3,95 6.00 6.00 33.90 14.95 14.95 Food Tax TOTAL DUE 79.75 7.78 87.53"
    ];
foreach ($rcpts as $rcpt) checktotal($rcpt);
```

The output for your test group is:

```
Total is $169.82
Total is $52.88
Total is $87.53
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing!